# Can I use a child class variables in its parent class?

Tags: object-oriented, objective-c, inheritance

I am programming in Objective C, iOS. I create a `Class A` which is a parent class, and `Class B` inherits to `Class A`.

Now I have `Class B` variables which I also need to use in `Class A`. And also one another `Class C`, `Class A` add in `Class C` (not inherits), and I want to use `Class B` variables in `Class C`.

How can I access? I have created object also but not working, is that possible to access?

Comment: Why can't you move ClassB's variables to ClassA?

Comment: What are you trying to model? What you're trying to do seems to go against OO. Almost surely there is a better way to model your problem, which doesn't involve ClassA knowing anything about ClassB.

Comment: I m not sure that its possible or not, So that's why i am asking here, can i access variable of class B in class A ?

Comment: @Jagdish A piece of general asking advice: provide a lot of context. Enough people, reading this Q&A, can detect a rotten architecture from a mile and providing more context will help them guide you in the right direction on the meta-problem that made you post here in the first place :)

Comment: @K.Steff thnaks for giving me advice in right direction.. Next time i will keep in mind this point. thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now I have Class B variables which I also need to use in Class A. And
>   also one another Class C, Class A add in Class C (not inherits), and I
>   want to use Class B variables in Class C.
>
> How can I access?

**Short answer:** No, you can't do what you propose.

**Longer, more detailed explanation:**
Classes don't have variables -- objects do. They're called *instance variables* (or *ivars* for short) because they're variables that are associated with an *instance* of a class, which is to say an object. You declare the variables in the class declaration, of course, but they aren't actually created until the class is *instantiated*, that is, until an *instance* (an object) of the class is created.

So, if you have this:

```
ClassA *objectA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
ClassB *objectB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
```

then `objectA` is an instance of ClassA, and `objectB` is an instance of ClassB. Let's also stipulate (as you have in your question) that ClassB is a subclass of ClassA. That is, it's declared like:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    int foo;
}

@interface ClassB : ClassA
{
    int bar;
}
```

So to get to your question... `objectA` has an instance variable called `foo`, plus any that it inherits from NSObject. `objectB` has an instance variable called `bar`, and it also inherits `foo` from ClassA and whatever ClassA gets from NSObject. `objectA` does *not* have an ivar called `bar`, and trying to access it would cause an error:

```
objectA->foo = 1;    // OK
objectB->foo = 2;    // OK
objectA->bar = 3;    // Error!
objectB->bar = 4;    // OK
```

This is because any instance of ClassB is also an instance of ClassA (that's the effect of inheritance) but an instance of ClassA is not necessarily an instance of ClassB. It's okay for code in ClassA to refer to variables or properties in ClassB, but only if it knows that it's dealing with an instance of ClassB. So you could have a method like:

```
- (void)addBar:(ClassB*)someB
{
    foo += someB->bar;
}
```

That's okay because you know that `someB` is supposed to be an instance of ClassB. What you can't do in ClassA is:

```
- (void)addBar:(ClassB*)someB
{
    bar += someB->bar;    // Error! ClassA doesn't have a 'bar' ivar!
}
```

because, again, ClassA doesn't have an ivar named `bar`.

By the way, even the first example isn't great form -- unless there's a good reason, it's better to avoid the situation where a class (like ClassA) is dependent on its own subclass (like ClassB).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to move ClassB's variables to ClassA?

If not then maybe you could add whatever the Obj-C equivalent of pure virtual functions/interface is to ClassA, that ClassB must implement, so that ClassA can use the variables. Then ClassC could also access them through this interface.

Comment: No not possible to move ClassB's variable to ClassA..

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

That can't be done because parent classes are totally oblivious of it's children.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One Question for you, 

Class A : Class W
Class B : Class W

Now can pass method of Class B to Class A ?

Comment: That allows for a program that uses objects of type W, to call all methods defined in W on them, regardless of they beeing B or A under the hood. One problem here is that in your question you say "Class B inherits to Class A". You cannot inherit to, you only can inherit from. So the question is a little bit ambiguos since one cannot tell if you meant A is the superclass or the other way around.